# Can C547B transistors be used to build H-Bridge?

Tags: arduino, transistors, dc-motor

I've collected many C547B transistors from an old UPS, Can I use these to build h-bridge to control DC motors from Arduino?

Comment: Theoretically yes, but keep in mind that those transistors are rated for a collector to base current of 100 mA, too little for most motors. Furthemore, you need rather complicated driving circuitry to turn the high side on since you need a voltage higher than that of the DC bus used for the H bridge. I suggest that you should just get a motor driver IC, for example the [SN754410](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn754410.pdf). It, for example, has 4 half bridge outputs that you can use for controlling a stepper motor, two 1A DC motors or even a single 2A DC motor when paralleled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: It depends on what voltage you are using for your motor but most likely you will need some other parts to make exactly what you need.

This is the simplest and most common H-bridge circuit that you will find on the internet:

[image: H bridge]

The motor can be controlled according to this truth table:

[image: truth table]

As you can see this circuit uses PNP at the top and NPN at the bottom.

And this is what you are planning to make:

[image: NPN bridge]

If you use all NPN, you will need a voltage higher than the supply voltage of your motor to drive the upper part of H Bridge. So, if your motor is running on 3V, you will be able to drive your NPN using 5V of arduino. However if the motor is running on 5V or higher, you are in trouble. Again, I haven't considered the current consumption of your motor because you haven't provided the details about your motor. You need to check whether the transistor satisfies the current requirement of your motors.

My suggestion: If you want to use it in a real project, I'd suggest you to use a commonly available H bridge (L293D, L298) which have a simpler interface, and some protection against accidental shorting.

If you want to make an H bridge for learning, then try making  the first circuit as it will allow you to control motors running on a wide voltage range.

If you want to make NPN H bridge, you can make that too but keep in mind you have to use 1-4V supply for your motor. Also, do not forget the protection diodes or your transistor will get destroyed due to the spikes generated due to the motor while switching. Refer to first circuit for the protection diodes.